# How do I manually change the "Balance" shown on Chart of Accounts?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

I am trying to reset the balance to all accounts in Charts of Accounts to $0. I can go in and manually delete every item and edit opening balances but I couldn't find a way to do it quickly either through scripting or CSV import. Any help would be appreciated

I have tried searching through transactions and editing transactions to delete items purchased but that would take hundreds of hours to go through each transaction to make all my accounts have a balance of $0. I tried CSV imports to update information but I am unable to touch the "Balance" from a CSV upload. If there is a way to add balance to the account form I could probably do it from there but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do that I supposed you want to re-setup the system without deleting the history transactions ?

I think you can post a journal to reverse the balance for each account that you pull from trial balance report as at the last day before the period you want to restart.

E.g. if AP account has a credit balance of 100k. Your journal line will be Ap account debit 100K etc..

You may also want to consult NetSuite account manager. NETSUITE may be able to help to do mass data deletion without changing the setup.